# How to plot the magnitude and phase of a frequency?

Tags: matlab, plot, signal-processing, fft, frequency-domain

I was reading [Practical Introduction to Frequency Domain Analysis](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/examples/practical-introduction-to-frequency-domain-analysis.html). It shows how to observe the frequency content of a signal using this code:

```c
Fs = 44100;
y = audioread('guitartune.wav');

NFFT = length(y);
Y = fft(y,NFFT);
F = ((0:1/NFFT:1-1/NFFT)*Fs).';

magnitudeY = abs(Y);        % Magnitude of the FFT
phaseY = unwrap(angle(Y));  % Phase of the FFT

helperFrequencyAnalysisPlot1(F,magnitudeY,phaseY,NFFT)
```

The function that plots is the `helperFrequencyAnalysisPlot1`. I need to know how the function does the plotting but the article never shows how. How is it actually done?

Comment: Would `edit helperFrequencyAnalysisPlot1` show you the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are Matlab built-in examples so you have to type in the Command Window

```
edit('helperFrequencyAnalysisPlot1.m')
```

A new Matlab editor tab will pop up, showing you the function (both its definition and the code).

Comment: @templateboy Even better, the help page you link to has links to the function at the very bottom. Examining the URL shows that the link points to `matlab:edit('helperFrequencyAnalysisPlot1.m')`, just as @Alessiox suggests.